# Duplicate code Javascript. how to modularize it

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I am facing a duplicate issue in Sonar and i am not able to figure out how to correct it.
Here is the sample code. Please not formFields passed is immutable state maintained in my project. So if i do `formFields.getIn(['home', 'value'])`, i am trying to get the value of particular field `home` in this case. and i compare all values with `'true'`. and once i compare i push its respective string in `lifeEvents`. These lines (3,4 and 5,6) show tat i am duplicating the comparison and pushing of data to the array.

```
1. export const getLifeEvents = formFields => {
2.  const lifeEvents = [];
3.    if(formFields.getIn(['home', 'value']) === 'true')
4.      lifeEvents.push("Buy home");
5.    if(formFields.getIn(['married', 'value']) === 'true')
6.      lifeEvents.push("Getting married");
7.  return lifeEvents;
8. }
```

To avoid this duplication, i tried the following

```
export const getLifeEvents = formFields => {
  const lifeEvents = [];
  const Info = {
    title: ['home', 'married'],
    text: ['Buy home', 'Getting married']
  }

  const data = Info.title.map((e, i) => {
    return { title: e, text: Info.text[i]
  }

  const result = data && data.map(item => {
    if(formFields.getIn([item.title, 'value']) === 'true')
      lifeEvents.push(item.text);
    return lifeEvents;
  });
}
```

When i do this, i always get undefined. can someone suggest please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object with the keys and text. Loop over it with reduce

```
const myEvents = {
  home: 'Buy home',
  married: 'Getting married'
};


export const getLifeEvents = formFields => {
  return Object.entries(myEvents).reduce((lifeEvents, [key, text]) => {
    if (formFields.getIn([key, 'value']) === 'true') {
      lifeEvents.push(text);
    }
    return lifeEvents;
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: @epascarello- lifeEvents.push("Buy home");. This is not the same always. Even the strings i am pushing to the array are different for each field

Comment: just a copy and paste error, forgot to add the variable